# <library-name>.aar file not generating gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, aar

in my project i have a library. i want to use that librarie's aar file in the project. before updating studio to 1.10 and and gradle to 1.0.0 it was working fine. an aar file was generating with name libname.aar.also libname-release.aar, libname-debug.aar will be there. now libname.aar is not generating in aar folder. now libname-release.aar, libname-debug.aar only generating. How to resolve this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I hope somebody answers soon.

Comment: i guess , upon updation andoroid studio,sdk,gradle now it is only generating release and debug versions of aar file. i am taking the release version instead of previous one. it works well. try it.

Comment: I was actually having the problem where only the debug version was being built. The problem was that Lint was stopping the build from finishing, I had to add this to my build.gradle:

        lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }